# How can I fix ic_launcher (aka com.myapp.live:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found

Tags: android

I had an app that was working find but I noticed that the icon was not changed. So I went in to change it and now no matter what I do, I cannot get it to create an apk or bundle. Below is what I have and the errors.

I am using Android Studio latest version download

This is NOT a duplicate that has a resolution. All of the suggested questions, and questions I searched for did not have a resolution that worked. (If I missed one that fixes this, then I apologize)

What I have done:
Besides the 3 days of endless searches on here and google, I have added a new image asset through "File", "mipmap", and "app". I also removed ALL of the filed in mipmap and tried again. I also went through a manifest of a new project and copied and pasted the Application stuff (with my own stuff) in it.

**Please note:** I AM NOT EDITING THE RELEASE MANIFEST... this is just being added to show you what the error is showing.

First the main error in the log:

**"Android resource linking failed
W:\Live6\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:13: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.live.plive:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
W:\Live6\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:13: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.live.plive:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.
error: failed processing manifest."**

Now the error in release manifest

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.pLive" >
```

Which is the same in my main manifest

**Note:** I also havge ic_launcher, ic_launcher_foreground, and ic_launcher_round in my mipmap

Here is in my main manifest:

````
    <application


        tools:replace="android:icon"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.pLive"
        tools:targetApi="s">
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking for the answer. I solved it by doing the ADD IMAGE ASSET 3 times. You have to do it as a normal way (release) then also again as "Main" and also add it through the Drawable as "Debug". Once you have all three, go through mipmap and click on every one of them. The ones not in use will delete. You will still see the android default in a couple XML files, however when you make the bundle or a test APK it will show your custom icon you made. I hope this helps anyone that comes accross this question.